# Safari on MAC skipping input fields

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having a little problem on a form, which has two inputs fields, which indicates time ( format HH:mm ) that are really closer, something like this:

[image]

This is the HTML part

```
<label>
    <span>Hour*</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="ev.date_mn" name="ev_date_mn" placeholder="00" maxlength="2" required/>
    <span class="divider">:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm" ng-model="ev.date_hr" name="ev_date_hr" placeholder="00" maxlength="2" required/>
</label>
```

And this is the respective CSS part

```
.wrapper.crea-evento div.input-group div.input-section label > span {
    width: 40%;
}

.wrapper.crea-evento div.input-group div.input-section label > span.divider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 5px;
    float: right;
}

.wrapper.crea-evento div.input-group div.input-section input {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.wrapper.crea-evento div.input-group div.input-section input.input-sm {
    width: 65px;
}
```

The problem comes up, only on Safari, when i click on the first input of these ( hours ), it automatically focuses the second one ( minutes ). The only way to write on hours input field is by using `TAB` key on keyboard, which obviously isn't the best solution.

On Chrome, Firefox and IE ( 9+, Edge too ) works fine, only Safari has this behaviour. Could it be a `webkit` bug? I've read about this "autofocus" by Safari, but only on mobile, not on desktop

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; the `label` element can contain, at most, only one form element.

Comment: @Shaggy yes, I thought about that, so why does it work on FF, IE and Chrome?

Comment: It doesn't "work"; given that the HTML is invalid, each browser is attempting to somehow provide focus to one of the `input` elements, it just so happens that Chrome, FF & IE end up providing focus to the same one, the first one. Safari is either providing focus to the last `input` or each `input` in succession. But, again, the browser is not the issue here, it's the invalid HTML.

Comment: @Shaggy, yes, that was actually the problem. It works on all browsers now, what a stupid error... Just 2 hours until holidays you know :)

Please, can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid; the `label` element can only contain, at most, one form element. Given that the HTML is invalid, each browser is attempting to somehow provide focus to one of the `input` elements, it just so happens that Chrome, Firefox & Internet Explorer/Edge end up providing focus to the same one, the first one. Safari is either providing focus to the last `input` or each `input` in succession.

The "solution" therefore is to rewrite your HTML so that each `label` is only associated with one `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Safari is wrong here with respect to the HTML5 standard:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element

> If the for attribute is not specified, but the label element has a labelable element descendant, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element’s labeled control.
>
> If a label element has interactive content other than its labeled control, the activation behavior of the label element for events targeted at those interactive content descendants and any descendants of those must be to do nothing.

It should behave like all other browsers do. This is a Safari bug that is still present in iOS 11.3.

Comment: It most definitely is a bug, there should never be feature in a browser where i click in one field to focus on another one instead; it should be perfectly natural to group multiple fields within the same label;